# extract data from only columns matching character strings

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks something like this (but much larger)

```
Jul_08 <- c(1,0,2,0,3)
Aug_08 <- c(0,0,1,0,1)
Sep_08 <- c(0,1,0,0,1)
month<-c("Jul_08","Aug_08","Jul_08","Sep_08","Jul_08")
dataset <- data.frame(Jul_08 = Jul_08, Aug_08 = Aug_08, Sep_08=Sep_08,month=month)
```

For each row, I would to isolate the value for a select month only as indicated by the "month" field. In other words, for a given row, if the column "month" = Jul_08, then for a new "value" column, I would like to include the datum that pertained to the column "Jul_08" from that row.

In essence, the output would add this value column to the dataset

```
value<-c(1,0,2,0,3)
```

Creating this final dataset

```
dataset.value<-cbind(dataset,value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use matrix indexing:

```
w <- match(month, names(dataset))

dataset$value <- dataset[ cbind(seq_len(nrow(dataset)), w) ]
```

Here the `w` vector tells R which column to take the value from and `seq_len` is used to say use the same row, so the `value` column is constructed by taking the 1st column in the 1st row, then the 2nd column and 2nd row, 1st column for the 3rd row, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply` :

```
value <- unlist(lapply(1:nrow(dataset),
                function(r){ 
                   dataset[r,as.character(dataset[r,'month'])] 
                }))
> value
[1] 1 0 2 0 3
```

Or, alternatively :

```
value <- diag(as.matrix(dataset[,as.character(dataset$month)]))
> value
[1] 1 0 2 0 3
```

Then you can `cbind` the new column as you did in your example.

Some notes:

- I prefer `unlist(lapply(...))` over `sapply` since *automagic* simplification implemented in sapply function tends to surprise me sometimes. But I'm pretty sure this time you can use it without any problem.
- `as.character` is necessary only if `month` column is a factor (as in the example), otherwise is redundant (but I would leave it, just to be safe).